# Plotly: How to create a scatter plot for each variable in a dataframe with a For Loop?

Tags: python, plotly

I need help to do a for loop to create a scatterplot that shows me two variables grouped by a system.
My df is:

```
WTG     Power    WSPD
A0201   2000     12.1
A0202   1800     9.7
A0201   1000     6.6
A0202   1150     7.8
A0203   760      5.8
A0203   1353     8.8
```

So what I need is a scatterplot for each turbine with the x axis being the WSPD and the y axis being Power.

Thanks!

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

[Plotly express](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.scatter) is perfect for this. No `For Loop` needed

```
fig = px.scatter(df, x='WSPD', y = 'Power', color = 'WTG')
```

[image]

But if a `For Loop` for some reason suits you better, you can use [plotly.graph_objects](https://plotly.com/python/graph-objects/):

```
fig = go.Figure()
colors = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly
for i, cat in enumerate(df['WTG'].unique()):
    dfp = df[df['WTG']==cat]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dfp['WSPD'], y = dfp['Power'],
                             mode = 'markers',
                             marker_color = colors[i]))
fig.show()
```

#### Complete code, plotly express:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'WTG': {0: 'A0201',
                          1: 'A0202',
                          2: 'A0201',
                          3: 'A0202',
                          4: 'A0203',
                          5: 'A0203'},
                     'Power': {0: 2000, 1: 1800, 2: 1000, 3: 1150, 4: 760, 5: 1353},
                     'WSPD': {0: 12.1, 1: 9.7, 2: 6.6, 3: 7.8, 4: 5.8, 5: 8.8}})

fig = px.scatter(df, x='WSPD', y = 'Power', color = 'WTG')
fig.show()
```

#### Complete code, plotly graph objects:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'WTG': {0: 'A0201',
                          1: 'A0202',
                          2: 'A0201',
                          3: 'A0202',
                          4: 'A0203',
                          5: 'A0203'},
                     'Power': {0: 2000, 1: 1800, 2: 1000, 3: 1150, 4: 760, 5: 1353},
                     'WSPD': {0: 12.1, 1: 9.7, 2: 6.6, 3: 7.8, 4: 5.8, 5: 8.8}})


fig = go.Figure()
colors = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly
for i, cat in enumerate(df['WTG'].unique()):
    dfp = df[df['WTG']==cat]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dfp['Power'], y = dfp['WSPD'],
                             mode = 'markers',
                             marker_color = colors[i],
                             name = cat))
fig.show()
```

Comment: Hey my friend,
So I need a plot for each unique WTG because I have more than 1000 data points for each.
The code is not working because it says "list index out of range"

Comment: @NLGenin That only happens for the latter approach, right? It's because the `colors` list is limited. Pleases try with the first suggestion. If that doesn't work, I can expand the last one with a more dynamic functionality for the colors.